# UIPopoverController backgroundColor fails to set color using colorWithPatternImage

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller, uicolor

I'm trying to set the background Color of UIPopover with backgroundColor property introduced in iOS 7.

It works when i set the color using normal color methods but doesn't work when I use image pattern based method.

Here is the code -

```
- (IBAction)tapTestButton:(UIButton *)sender
    SecondViewController *secondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondVC];

    self.pc = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:nc];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"];
    self.pc.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];   // However [UIColor redColor] works !!
    [self.pc presentPopoverFromRect:sender.frame inView:sender.superview permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

Below screenshots captures the outcomes on simulator - notice the nav bar and arrow color (fyi - `bg.png` & `bg@2x.png` has blue texture).

[image]

**EDIT :**
It seems it is device specific (and simulator) issue. Of the 2 iPad devices i checked - it works on one (iPad 2nd gen, iOS 7.0.4) and not on the other (iPad 4th gen, iOS 7.0.4).

Comment: Why voted down? Please answer.

Comment: Even i got the same behaviour

Comment: You can do one thing, get the RGB color value from image and set color using [UIColor colorWithRed:(redValue)/255.0 green:(greenValue)/255.0 blue:(blueValue)/255.0 alpha:1.0]; Obviously it wont set the pattern image, but only color.